# Find cost for specific investment over last year in GnuCash

Tags: gnucash, cost-basis

I have a mutual fund account containing purchases over several years. Each year there are many individual purchases. The "Balance" column is useful for telling me the total *number of shares* purchased for a given year, but not the total *cost* of making those purchases. I would like to see the total amount of money used to make purchases of that mutual fund for a given time period, say the last year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reports -> I&E -> Cash Flow

Select the Mutual Fund account only.